# Append parameter in url on multiple checkbox group click

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, post

I want to rewrite url parameters values on checkbox click, similar to LinkedIn Advance search.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  
  $(document).ready(function () {
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
var seasoning = jQuery.map($(':checkbox[id=seasoning\\[\\]]:checked'), function (n, i) {return n.value;}).join(',');

window.location ='example.com?seasoning='+seasoning;
 
});

});
</script>
```

```html
<h3>Filter recepies:</h3>

<div>
<p>Select vegetables</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="vegetables[]" value="potato"> Potato</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="vegetables[]" value="onion"> Onion</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="vegetables[]" value="tomato"> Tomato</label><br>
</div>

<div>
<p>Select seasoning</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="seasoning[]" value="salt"> Salt</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="seasoning[]" value="pepper"> Pepper</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="seasoning[]" value="chilli"> Chilli Flakes</label><br>
</div>
```

My Desired Result

**Click1:** when I click Potato from  vegitable my URL should look like

**example.com?vegitables=potato**

**Click2:** when I click Onion from  vegitable my URL should look like

**example.com?vegitables=potato,onion**

**Click3:** when I click salt from  seasoning my URL should look like

**example.com?vegitables=potato,onion&seasoning=salt**

**Click4:** when I click pepper from  seasoning my URL should look like

**example.com?vegitables=potato,onion&seasoning=salt,pepper**

Comment: Check the answer i have posted, exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
  var seasoning = '', tempArray = [];
  $('input[name="vegetables[]"]:checked').each(function(){
      tempArray.push($(this).val());
  })
  if(tempArray.length !== 0){
     seasoning+='vegetables='+tempArray.toString();
     tempArray = [];
  }
  
  $('input[name="seasoning[]"]:checked').each(function(){
      tempArray.push($(this).val());
  })
  if(tempArray.length !== 0){
     seasoning+='&seasoning='+tempArray.toString();
  }
 
 // window.location ='example.com?seasoning='+seasoning;
 console.log('example.com?'+seasoning);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>Select vegetables</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="potato"> Potato</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="onion"> Onion</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vegetables[]" value="tomato"> Tomato</label><br>
</div>

<div>
<p>Select seasoning</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="salt"> Salt</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="pepper"> Pepper</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="seasoning[]" value="chilli"> Chilli Flakes</label><br>
</div>
```

For simplicity and further edit here is the link to working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r9yw7rxg/)

Comment: this is working like a charm for the 2 parameter (vegetables,seasoning)!
i am getting wrong value if i add 3rd parameter (vegetables,seasoning,param3)

js code for param3

$('input[name="param3[]"]:checked').each(function(){
      tempArray.push($(this).val());
  })
  if(tempArray.length !== 0){
     seasoning+='&param3='+tempArray.toString();
  }